# How to know the quality of query letter critiques?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, queries

Having nearly completed the second draft on my 135,000 word novel, I am now  seeking critiques of my query letter before I submit them to agents. I did find a forum at [AQ Connect - Query Critiques](http://agentqueryconnect.com/index.php?/forum/2-aq-connect-query-critiques/)  but I don't know how good it is.

How do I know if a site's critiques on a query letter contain good advice?

Comment: http://queryshark.blogspot.com/

Comment: Have edited the question to be more answerable; lists of links aren't something that can be a canonical answer, but asking about what to look for is. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I love Query Shark but there hasn't been any postings since last November. I am not sure it is still active. I have had no response from Agent Query either, I am not sure how long they take to accept a posting. Hopefully, there will be more suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

A query letter is a sales tool. The feedback you want is not from writers but from people in the business of selling books. I don't know that there is a reliable way to know if you are getting that on line. I think you would do much better to seek advice in person. Ideally, try to find someone in your area offering a workshop like this: http://quick-brown-fox-canada.blogspot.ca/search/label/How%20to%20Get%20Published.

But beyond the whole concept of a query letter, I would suggest going to writers conferences that offer you the opportunity to pitch directly to agents. A successful pitch in person will jump you ahead of all the people whose query letters are in the slush pile. Why? You showed more effort than they did, and you made a personal connection, which makes them feel more obliged to you than to someone who just bought a stamp.

Comment: I found this site and at least it forces to me state my story in a succinct manner and why an agent should ask me for additional chapters to review:  http://agentqueryconnect.com/index.php?/topic/36908-viral-some-things-are-best-left-dead/

Answer (score 1):

A query letter is supposed to be a "teaser." In it, you throw out bits and pieces of your work in order to whet the appetite of the agent, and get them to want "more." It will lay out a skeletal outline of your story, who the main characters are, what the conflict is, and what the desired result is, etc., to show that it makes sense. Depending on the type of work, you may want to withhold the actual result from your query letter, especially if it is a "twist" ending.

A good query critique will guide you in the above directions.